# Media Drive Permissions

Tags: nautilus, permissions, music

I just switched from a Hackintosh to Linux, and am trying to make sense of it. On my hackintosh, I partitioned a big drive into 3 parts--1 which holds music, 1 for film/tv, and one for the OS.  I installed Ubuntu onto the OS partition, and am now trying to make it so I can write to the media drives.

I've searched around and tried several things.  I tried gksu nautilus in Terminal, which brought me into root permissions.  When I select a folder and try to change permissions, I get "The owner could not be changed...Error setting owner: Read-only file system"

Ultimately, I have two specific aims:
- I want to make it so I can write to the film/tv drive from the ubuntu machine only
- I want to make it so I can write to the music drive from the ubuntu machine, or any other machine on the network (all Macs).  That is, I want a single music library (an iTunes file) that will serve all Mac laptops/iPads/iPhones on the network, but which XBMC on the Ubuntu machine can also see / read from.  Music will be *added to* the iTunes library via a single Mac laptop, but all other devices should be able to see the music drive.

Comment: The usual command for this is chown. Take a look at `chown --help` and `man chown`.

Comment: If you formatted the partitions under Mac, the filesystem is likely to be [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus). This is read-only under Linux. The best thing to do is to transfer all the files off those partitions, and then reformat them under [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to a filesystem type that is read-write under Linux, and can be accessed by other operating systems (FAT32, etc). Alternately, you could try and find a way to mount hfs+ as read-write. N.B. You can use `sudo parted -l` to  find the filesystem type.